# How can I add new columns efficiently using groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using [nba_py](https://github.com/seemethere/nba_py) to get the scoreboard data for some NBA matches.

Below is an example of how the data are structured:

```
    SEASON |     GAME_DATE_EST | GAME_SEQUENCE | GAME_ID | HOME_TEAM_ID | VISITOR_TEAM_ID | WINNER

0   2013    2013-10-05T00:00:00     1            11300001   12321         1610612760        V
1   2013    2013-10-05T00:00:00     2            11300002   1610612754    1610612741        V
2   2013    2013-10-05T00:00:00     3            11300003   1610612745    1610612740        V
3   2013    2013-10-05T00:00:00     4            11300004   1610612747    1610612744        H
4   2013    2013-10-06T00:00:00     1            11300005   12324         1610612755        V
```

**You can find a part of the data here: [NBA Games Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3IBC4_cZlMwRDZnOVI3MnZKeEE/view?usp=sharing).**

My aim is to create and add to the original data the following columns:

For the hometeam:

```
   1. Total wins/losses for hometeam if hometeam plays at home ("HOMETEAM_HOME_WINS"/"HOMETEAM_HOME_LOSSES")
   2. Total wins/losses for hometeam if hometeam is visiting ("HOMETEAM_VISITOR_WINS"/"HOMETEAM_VISITOR_LOSSES")
```

For the visitor_team:

```
   3. Total wins/losses for visitor_team if visitor_team plays at home ("VISITOR_TEAM_HOME_WINS"/"VISITOR_TEAM_HOME_LOSSES")
   4. Total wins/losses for visitor_team if visitor_team is visiting ("VISITOR_TEAM_VISITOR_WINS"/"VISITOR_TEAM_VISITOR_LOSSES")
```

My first simplistic approach is below:

```
def get_home_team_home_wins(x):
    hometeam = x.HOME_TEAM_ID
    season = x.SEASON
    gid = x.name
    season_hometeam_games = grouped_seasons_hometeams.get_group((season, hometeam))
    home_games = season_hometeam_games[(season_hometeam_games.index < gid)]

    if not home_games.empty:
        try:
            home_wins = home_games.FTR.value_counts()["H"]
        except Exception as e:
            home_wins = 0
    else:
        home_wins = 0

grouped_seasons_hometeams = df.groupby(["SEASON", "HOME_TEAM_ID"])

df["HOMETEAM_HOME_WINS"] = df.apply(lambda x: get_home_team_home_wins(x), axis=1)
```

Another approach is [iterating over the rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe?lq=1):

```
grouped_seasons = df.groupby("SEASON")
df["HOMETEAM_HOME_WINS"] = 0

current_season = 0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    season = row.SEASON
    if season != current_season:
        current_season = season
        season_games = grouped_seasons.get_group(current_season)

    hometeam = row.HOME_TEAM_ID
    gid = row.name
    games = season_games[(season_games.index < gid)]
    home_games = games[(games.HOME_TEAM_ID == hometeam)]

    if not home_games.empty:
        try:
            home_wins = home_games.FTR.value_counts()["H"]
        except Exception as e:
            home_wins = 0
    else:
        home_wins = 0

    row["HOME_TEAM_HOME_WINS_4"] = home_wins
    df.ix[index] = row
```

**Update 1:**

Below there are functions for getting wins/losses for hometeam if it plays at home and if it visits. A similar one would be for the visitor_team.

```
def get_home_team_home_wins_losses(x):
    hometeam = x.HOME_TEAM_ID
    season = x.SEASON
    gid = x.name

    games = df[(df.SEASON == season) & (df.index < gid)]
    home_team_home_games = games[(games.HOME_TEAM_ID == hometeam)]  


    # HOMETEAM plays at home
    if not home_team_home_games.empty:
        home_team_home_games_value_counts = home_team_home_games.FTR.value_counts()

        try:
            home_team_home_wins = home_team_home_games_value_counts["H"]
        except Exception as e:
            home_team_home_wins = 0

        try:
            home_team_home_losses = home_team_home_games_value_counts["V"]
        except Exception as e:
            home_team_home_losses = 0
    else:
        home_team_home_wins = 0
        home_team_home_losses = 0

    return [home_team_home_wins, home_team_home_losses]

def get_home_team_visitor_wins_losses(x):
    hometeam = x.HOME_TEAM_ID
    season = x.SEASON
    gid = x.name

    games = df[(df.SEASON == season) & (df.index < gid)]
    home_team_visitor_games = games[(games.VISITOR_TEAM_ID == hometeam)]

    # HOMETEAM visits
    if not home_team_visitor_games.empty:
        home_team_visitor_games_value_counts = home_team_visitor_games.FTR.value_counts()

        try:
            home_team_visitor_wins = home_team_visitor_games_value_counts["V"]
        except Exception as e:
            home_team_visitor_wins = 0

        try:
            home_team_visitor_losses = home_team_visitor_games_value_counts["H"]
        except Exception as e:
            home_team_visitor_losses = 0
    else:
        home_team_visitor_wins = 0
        home_team_visitor_losses = 0    

    return [home_team_visitor_wins, home_team_visitor_losses]

df["HOME_TEAM_HOME_WINS"], df["HOME_TEAM_HOME_LOSSES"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: get_home_team_home_wins_losses(x), axis=1))
df["HOME_TEAM_VISITOR_WINS"], df["HOME_TEAM_VISITOR_LOSSES"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: get_home_team_visitor_wins_losses(x), axis=1))
df["HOME_TEAM_WINS"] = df["HOME_TEAM_HOME_WINS"] + df["HOME_TEAM_VISITOR_WINS"]
df["HOME_TEAM_LOSSES"] = df["HOME_TEAM_HOME_LOSSES"] + df["HOME_TEAM_VISITOR_LOSSES"]
```

The above approaches are not efficient. So, I am thinking of using [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/groupby.html) but it's not really clear how.

I will add updates whenever I find something more efficient.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add sample data with structure? There are some fields (name, season) referenced that you do not explicitly show in data structure.

Comment: @Parfait I have added an example of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `transform()` but first conditionally create `HOMEWINNER` and `VISITWINNER` integer columns. Commented out are easier to read equivalent if/else calculations using `numpy.where()` which you may/may not have available as a package.

Do note `transform()` retains all rows but will aggregate by the IDs, so every record of a particular `HOME_TEAM_ID` should repeat values in these aggregate columns.:

```
nbadf['VISITWINNER'] =  [1 if x == 'V' else 0 for x in nbadf['WINNER']]
#nbadf['VISITWINNER'] = np.where(nbadf['WINNER']=='V', 1, 0)

nbadf['HOMEWINNER'] = [1 if x == 'H' else 0 for x in nbadf['WINNER']]    
#nbadf['HOMEWINNER'] = np.where(nbadf['WINNER']=='H', 1, 0)

nbadf['HOME_TEAM_WINS'] = nbadf.groupby(['HOME_TEAM_ID','SEASON'])\ 
                                        ['HOMEWINNER'].transform(sum)
nbadf['HOME_TEAM_LOSSES'] = nbadf.groupby(['HOME_TEAM_ID','SEASON'])\
                                          ['VISITWINNER'].transform(sum)

nbadf['VISIT_TEAM_WINS'] = nbadf.groupby(['VISITOR_TEAM_ID','SEASON'])\
                                         ['VISITWINNER'].transform(sum)
nbadf['VISIT_TEAM_LOSSES'] = nbadf.groupby(['VISITOR_TEAM_ID','SEASON'])\
                                           ['HOMEWINNER'].transform(sum)

nbadf.drop(['HOMEWINNER', 'VISITWINNER'],inplace=True,axis=1)

#   SEASON  ...  WINNER  HOME_TEAM_WINS  HOME_TEAM_LOSSES  VISIT_TEAM_WINS  VISIT_TEAM_LOSSES
#0    2013  ...      V               0                 1                1                  0
#1    2013  ...      V               0                 1                1                  0
#2    2013  ...      V               0                 1                1                  0
#3    2013  ...      H               1                 0                0                  1
#4    2013  ...      V               0                 1                1                  0
```

Now for instances of home teams later visiting and vice versa, consider a merge on the IDs with subsetted data frames (change column numbers if needed). This captures home teams who are also visitor teams. So run above aggregates on `mergedf` (and calculate same conditional `HOMEWINNER` using this time `WINNER_x` and `VISITWINNER` using `WINNER_y`):

```
# MERGES HOME SUBSET DF AND VISITOR SUBSET DF
mergedf = pd.merge(nbadf[[0,1,2,3,4,6]], nbadf[[0,1,2,3,5,6]],
                   left_on=['HOME_TEAM_ID'], right_on=['VISITOR_TEAM_ID'], how='inner')

mergedf['HOMETEAM_AS_VISITOR_WINS'] = mergedf.groupby(['VISITOR_TEAM_ID','SEASON_y'])\ 
                                                      ['VISITWINNER'].transform(sum)

mergedf['VISITORTEAM_AS_HOME_WINS'] = mergedf.groupby(['HOME_TEAM_ID','SEASON_x'])\ 
                                                      ['HOMEWINNER'].transform(sum)
```

Comment: In my case I will use cumsum. 
The HOME_TEAM_WINS/LOSSES  includes the games that the HOME_TEAM plays at home and respectively for VISIT_TEAM_WINS/LOSSES the VISITOR_TEAM visits, right

Comment: It should as the pair uses different IDs in groupby. Check results on larger data set.

Comment: What about when the HOME_TEAM visits and VISITOR_TEAM plays at home ?

Comment: Ah-hah! I almost added that part to original answer but did not want to confuse you. Consider a merge of home team and visitor team. See update.

Comment: The merge part is a bit confusing. How does it fit with the first part of your answer ? Also, I added a simple function to do what I need.

Comment: I think you should leave your answer, it was helpful. The code I have added with update 1 is just a step to finding something more efficient.